# Can all items be theoretically obtained from poke stops?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I had been in my first levels I had the impression I got one time an Incense from a pokestop, I was happy, because I like games where you can also gather cash items by ingame means, even may the chance be infinite small.

But since I never observed this again, it just might have been due to some kind of levelup mixed with visiting the stop or something like that, letting the Incense show up in the upper right corner with me assuming it was from the stop, but comming from the up instead.

So is there any refference about cash items can/can't be found in pokestops? (excluding normal pokeballs of course!)

Comment: As an aside, not directly what you've asked, but you can get "cash items by in game means" by adding your Pokemon to a gym and claiming the reward in the shop.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are a variety of items that cannot be obtained from Pokestops, and can only be obtained via level up rewards, such as incense, lucky eggs, incubators and lure modules.

There are also a variety of items that cannot be obtained at all currently, such as the master ball, varieties of incense and berries and other items like x attack, x defense, x miracle and troy disk.

The below is a list of items that can be obtained from a Pokestop:

- Pokeballs (including great and ultra variants)
- Potions (including super, hyper and max variants)
- Revives (including max variant)
- Eggs (2, 5 and 10km variants)

Comment: You can also get eggs

Comment: @JulienN true you can get eggs though they aren't items, updated anyway

Comment: Any resources? Or is this "just" global experience?

Answer (score 1):

Incubators, incenses and lure modulea cant be obtained from pokestops.

The incense you got was most likely in the very early levels to give you an idea what they're and hope you'll throw your money to them for more incenses